Flutter Survey Kit Progress Bar Always Shows 100% When Using Custom themeData
I'm using the Survey Kit package in my Flutter application to display a survey loaded from a JSON file. The survey displays correctly, and the progress bar works as expected when using the default theme.
Simplified code that works correctly:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:survey_kit/survey_kit.dart';

class MapForm extends StatelessWidget {
  const MapForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Future<Task> _loadTaskFromJson() async {
    final String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/forms/map.json');
    final Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
    return Task.fromJson(jsonMap);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Survey'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<Task>(
        future: _loadTaskFromJson(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final Task loadedTask = snapshot.data!;

              // Diagnostic output
              print('Task type: ${loadedTask.runtimeType}');
              print('Number of steps: ${loadedTask.steps.length}');
              for (var step in loadedTask.steps) {
                print('Step ID: ${step.stepIdentifier.id}');
                print('Step type: ${step.runtimeType}');
              }

              return SurveyKit(
                task: loadedTask,
                onResult: (SurveyResult result) {
                  // Handle survey result
                },
                showProgress: true,
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text('Error loading survey'));
            }
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Problem:
When I add custom themeData to style the survey (e.g., changing colors, fonts), the progress bar always shows 100% from the beginning of the survey. All other styling works as expected.
Here is the code where the problem occurs (with custom themeData):
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:survey_kit/survey_kit.dart';
import 'form_loader.dart';
import '../utils/db_handler.dart';
import '../screens/tests_results/map_results_screen.dart';
import 'package:project/widgets/gradient_background.dart';

class MapForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapFormState createState() => _MapFormState();
}

class _MapFormState extends State<MapForm> {
  late Future<Task> _taskFuture;
  final dbHandler = DbHandler();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _taskFuture = FormLoader.loadTaskFromJson('assets/forms/map.json');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GradientBackground(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: const Text(
            'survey title',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        body: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: FutureBuilder<Task>(
            future: _taskFuture,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Task> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'error 1:\n${snapshot.error}',
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                  final Task task = snapshot.data!;
                  return SurveyKit(
                    onResult: (SurveyResult result) async {
                      if (result.finishReason == FinishReason.COMPLETED) {
                        try {
                          final String resultId = await dbHandler
                              .storeTestResult('map', result.toJson());

                          await Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  MapResultsScreen(id: resultId),
                            ),
                          );
                        } catch (e) {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(
                              content: Text(
                                'Błąd: error x. $e',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      } else if (result.finishReason ==
                          FinishReason.DISCARDED) {
                        context.pushReplacement('/main');
                      }
                    },
                    task: task,
                    showProgress: true,
                    localizations: const <String, String>{
                      'cancel': 'translation1',
                      'next': 'translation2',
                      'submit': 'translation3',
                    },
                    themeData: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                      primaryColor: Colors.white,
                      appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        elevation: 0,
                        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(
                        cursorColor: Colors.white,
                        selectionColor: Colors.white70,
                        selectionHandleColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                          minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                            const Size(150.0, 60.0),
                          ),
                          side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                            (Set<MaterialState> state) {
                              if (state.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                                return const BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                );
                              }
                              return const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                            (Set<MaterialState> state) {
                              if (state.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                                return Theme.of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .labelLarge
                                    ?.copyWith(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    );
                              }
                              return Theme.of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .labelLarge
                                  ?.copyWith(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                          textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                            Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge?.copyWith(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      textTheme: const TextTheme(
                        headlineSmall: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                        bodyMedium: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                        bodySmall: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                        titleMedium: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                      inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                      ),
                      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        onPrimary: Colors.black,
                        background: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                    ),
                    surveyProgressbarConfiguration: SurveyProgressConfiguration(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white54,
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'another error message.',
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'another error message',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Question:
Why does the progress bar always show 100% when using custom themeData with SurveyKit? How can I apply custom styling to my survey without affecting the progress bar functionality?
What I've tried:
Removing themeData: When I remove the custom themeData, the progress bar works correctly, indicating that the issue is related to the theme.
Modifying textTheme: I suspected that overriding certain text styles might affect the progress bar, so I tried keeping displayMedium unchanged, but the problem persists.
Additional information:
JSON file:
{
  "id": "test",
  "type": "navigable",
  "rules": [
    {
      "type": "direct",
      "triggerStepIdentifier": { "id": "intro" },
      "destinationStepIdentifier": { "id": "question1" }
    }
  ],
  "steps": [
    {
      "stepIdentifier": { "id": "question1" },
      "type": "question",
      "title": "Question 1",
      "text": "What is your favorite color?",
      "answerFormat": {
        "type": "single",
        "textChoices": [
          { "text": "Red", "value": "red" },
          { "text": "Blue", "value": "blue" }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "stepIdentifier": { "id": "question2" },
      "type": "question",
      "title": "Question 2",
      "text": "What is your favorite animal?",
      "answerFormat": {
        "type": "single",
        "textChoices": [
          { "text": "Cat", "value": "cat" },
          { "text": "Dog", "value": "dog" }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "stepIdentifier": { "id": "completion" },
      "type": "completion",
      "title": "Thank you!",
      "text": "You have completed the survey.",
      "buttonText": "Finish"
    }
  ]
}

Diagnostic output:
Task type: NavigableTask
Number of steps: 3
Step ID: question1
Step type: QuestionStep
Step ID: question2
Step type: QuestionStep
Step ID: completion
Step type: CompletionStep


I tried running the exact example provided by you and the progress indicator displays correctly for me and advances after each step. Are you sure you're not missing something?

Also, calling the _loadTaskFromJson future directly in build can result in undesired effects. The future will restart whenever your widget rebuilds. Your MapForm should be a stateful widget and you should create a field for your future in your state and start the future there or in initState. And pass this field as the parameter to the FutureBuilder in your build. See FutureBuilder's docs. You can verify this with a simple hot reload–currently your survey will restart if you hot reload. It won't after this change.

Actually! The problem occurs after trying to add Custom ThemeData. I updated the question. The first script works, but after adding themeData and styling - the progress bar stops working and appears as if it was still 100%

Your progress bar is not always on 100%, but it appears so because you are setting your app's primary color to Colors.white in the themeData parameter passed to the SurveyKit widget:
themeData: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
   primaryColor: Colors.white,
   ...
)

The progress bar is displayed using the SurveyProgress widget and in its source, it can be seen that if you do not pass a valueProgressbarColor, it uses ThemeData.primaryColor which you have specified to be Colors.white:
 color: progressbarConfiguration.valueProgressbarColor 
    ?? Theme.of(context).primaryColor,

The solution is to pass your desired progress bar color in the surveyProgressbarConfiguration parameter of your SurveyKit widget. Use the valueProgressbarColor and progressbarColor parameters to set the colors of the progress bar:
surveyProgressbarConfiguration: SurveyProgressConfiguration(
    valueProgressbarColor: Colors.red // Replace with the color of your choice
    progressbarColor: Colors.blue, // Replace with the color of your choice
),

